# Search Cursor cannot access hosted table in ArcGIS Online using Notebooks

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-online, cursor, hosted-feature-layer, arcgis-notebook

I am receive a Runtime Error when using a Search Cursor on a hosted Table in ArcGIS Online and I cannot figure out why. I am using an AGOL Notebook. The message is that it cannot access the Table. Full editing is allowed on the table and my user is the owner.

```
import pandas, arcgis, arcpy
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from statistics import mean
import numpy as np
import datetime
from getpass import getpass

# Sign in
gis = GIS("home")

tableURL = "https://services.arcgis.com/qnjIrwR8z5Izc0ij/arcgis/rest/services/MLIACollectionsMonthly/FeatureServer/0"

### Create Trend Line table entry ###
def best_fit_slope_and_intercept(xs,ys):
    m = (((mean(xs)*mean(ys)) - mean(xs*ys)) / ((mean(xs)*mean(xs)) - 
    mean(xs*xs)))

    b = mean(ys) - m*mean(xs)

    return m, b
    def calculate_trend(table, value_field, date_field, trend_field, num_days, 
    category_field, trend_daily_change_field):
    table = tableURL
    value_field = "month_collect_total"
    date_field = "date"
    trend_field = "collect_trend"
    num_days = 360
    category_field = "geography"
    trend_daily_change_field = "collect_change"

    search_fields = [value_field, date_field]
    if len(category_field) > 0:
        search_fields.append(category_field)

    category_values = {}
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, search_fields) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            category = "all"
            if len(category_field) > 0:
                category = row[2]

            if category is None:
                continue

            if category not in category_values:
                category_values[category] = {'max_date' : None, 'values' : []}
        
            values = category_values[category]
            v = row[0]
            d = row[1]
            if d is None or v is None:
                continue
            if values['max_date'] == None or values['max_date'] < d:
                values['max_date'] = d
            values['values'].append([d, v])

    for k, v in category_values.items():
        if v['max_date'] is None:
            continue
    
        min_date = v['max_date'] - datetime.timedelta(days=num_days)
    
        x_list = []
        y_list = []
        for value in v['values']:
            if value[0] > min_date:
                x_list.append(int(value[0].timestamp()))
                y_list.append(value[1])

        if len(y_list) < 2:
            continue

        xs = np.array(x_list, dtype=np.float64)
        ys = np.array(y_list, dtype=np.float64)

        m, b = best_fit_slope_and_intercept(xs,ys)

        where_clause = "1=1"
        if len(category_field) > 0:
            where_clause = "{0} = '{1}'".format(category_field, k)

        daily_change = ((m*(int(v['max_date'].timestamp())))+b) -  ((m* 
(int((v['max_date'] - datetime.timedelta(days=1)).timestamp())))+b)

        update_fields = [date_field, trend_field]
        if len(trend_daily_change_field) > 0:
            update_fields.append(trend_daily_change_field)
    
        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(table, update_fields, where_clause) as cursor:
            for row in cursor:
                if row[0] > min_date:
                    row[1] = (m*(int(row[0].timestamp())))+b
                    if len(trend_daily_change_field) > 0:
                        row[2] = daily_change
                else:
                    row[1] = None
                    if len(trend_daily_change_field) > 0:
                        row[2] = None

                cursor.updateRow(row)
        del cursor
    
    
    print("Complete")

    RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-21-df64dc63df0d> in <module>
          1 # Calculate trend for collections
    ----> 2 calculate_trend(tableURL, "month_collect_total", "date", "collect_trend", 360, "county", 
    "collect_change")

    <ipython-input-20-2d85229df245> in calculate_trend(table, value_field, date_field, trend_field, 
    num_days, category_field, trend_daily_change_field)
         20 
         21     category_values = {}
    ---> 22     with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, search_fields) as cursor:
         23         for row in cursor:
         24             category = "all"

     RuntimeError: cannot open 'https://services.arcgis.com/qnjIrwR8z5Izc0ij/arcgis/rest/services/MLIACollectionsMonthly/FeatureServer/0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your process works for me using ArcGIS Online Advanced Notebooks. You've only provided a snippet of your code. My only suggestion is to check the **table** variable you're passing into the SearchCursor and make sure it's correct. Per the error, it seems like it's just the URL as I've used it.... so its hard to say. Perhaps just the timing of your attempt that it couldn't access the service?

```
import arcpy
url = "https://services.arcgis.com/qnjIrwR8z5Izc0ij/arcgis/rest/services/MLIACollectionsMonthly/FeatureServer/0"
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(url, "*") as cursor:
    for r in cursor:
        print(r)
```

> (1, 'Beaverhead', datetime.datetime(2005, 8, 1, 12, 0), 734.25,
> 734.25, None, None) (2, 'Beaverhead', datetime.datetime(2005, 9, 1, 12, 0), 621.75, 1356.0, None, None) (3, 'Beaverhead',
> datetime.datetime(2005, 10, 1, 12, 0), 637.5, 1993.5, None, None)

Comment: Thank you for your response KHbma. Here is more of the code. I have tried accessing it for last couple days. Here is the code in full. When I run the scrip with Pycharm or ArcGIS Pro it is able to search and update the hosted table. It does not work only when the script is run with notebooks.